# Is there a way to use custom variables in Azure Pipelines conditions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to do something like this

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['abc'], 'dev') }}:
    someOtherVariable: '123'
```

with a variable defined via UI here:

[image]

It doesn't work. `someOtherVariable` is not defined after this.
Is there a way to use this variable in conditions? What should be the syntax?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct but doesn't seem to work for conditions that rely on variables within the block where variables are defined for custom variables.

It is one of the (many) quirks of the Azure Pipelines YAML processing pipeline. Some conditions, variables, templates, syntax is only available at specific stages of the YAML processing and it depends on whether you are in a pipeline, template, or decorator.

Simplest solution is to use a script step to set the variable and optionally make that step conditional:

```
    ${{ if eq(variables['condition'], 'true') }}:
      script: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=someOtherVariable]123'
```

or rely on [one of my tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks) to do that on your behalf:

```
- task: SetVariable@1
  inputs:
    name: 'someOtherVariable'
    value: '123'
  condition: eq(variables['condition'], 'true')
```

or:

```
${{ if eq(variables['condition'], 'true') }}:
- task: SetVariable@1
  inputs:
    name: 'someOtherVariable'
    value: '123'
```