# Setting YAML template variable at runtime is not usable in condition or expression

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

No matter what approach I take, I can't seem to use the value of a yaml variable that is being set at runtime in an expression or condition.

Synopsis: Calling pipeline calls template pipeline. Template pipeline sets variable to be used in condition. i.e.

```yaml
- ${{ if and(eq(parameters.checkinUpdatedSubmoduleCommits, true), eq(variables['isDevBranch'], true)) }}:
#<Do some work>
```

callingPipeline.yaml

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: buildConfiguration
    displayName: Build Configuration
    type: string
    default: Release
    values:
      - Release
      - Debug
  - name: checkinUpdatedSubmoduleCommits
    displayName: Do you want to checkin updated submodule commits on the Dev branch?
    type: boolean
    default: false  

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Repo-MyProj
      type: git
      name: Org/MyProj  
      ref: DevBranch
      trigger:
      - DevBranch

variables:
  reporef: $[ resources.repositories['Repo-MyProj'].ref]

pool:
  name: MyBuildAgent

trigger: none

jobs:
  - template: 'template.yaml'
    parameters:
      buildConfiguration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
      checkinUpdatedSubmoduleCommits: '${{ parameters.checkinUpdatedSubmoduleCommits }}'
```

template.yaml

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: buildConfiguration
    type: string
  - name: checkinUpdatedSubmoduleCommits
    type: boolean
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: |      
      $isRepoRefEq = "$(reporef)" -eq "refs/heads/DevBranch"
      Write-Host "isRepoRefEq = $isRepoRefEq"
      $val = $false
      if( "$(reporef)" -eq "refs/heads/DevBranch") {
        $val = $true          
      }
      Write-Host val = $val
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isDevBranchOut;isOutput=true]$val"         
    name: 'setVar'

- job: MainJob
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    group: TMPL_VARS
    statVar: 'testValue'
    isDevBranch: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setVar.isDevBranchOut'] ]
  continueOnError: false
  workspace:
    clean: outputs
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo templateVarRepoRef = $(reporef)
      echo isEqTmplRepoRef = ${{ eq(variables['reporef'], 'refs/heads/DevBranch') }}      
      echo pwsh isDevBranch = $(isC5DevBranch)
      echo value1 isDevBranch = ${{ variables['isDevBranch'] }}
      echo value2 isDevBranch = ${{ variables.isDevBranch }}
      echo istrue isDevBranch = ${{ eq(variables['isDevBranch'], true) }}
      echo value1 statVar = ${{ variables['statVar'] }}
      echo value2 statVar = ${{ variables.statVar }}
      echo eq statVar = ${{ eq(variables['statVar'], 'testValue') }}
    displayName: Display Parameters' Values
```

Output for Job A:setVar Task

```
isRepoRefEq = True
val = True
Finishing: setVar
```

Output for Display Parameters' Values

```
templateVarRepoRef = refs/heads/DevBranch #Correct
isEqTmplRepoRef = False      #Wrong
pwsh isDevBranch = True #Correct
value1 isDevBranch = $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setVar.isDevBranchOut'] ] #Wrong
value2 isDevBranch = $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setVar.isDevBranchOut'] ] #Wrong
istrue isDevBranch = False #Wrong
value1 statVar = testValue #Correct
value2 statVar = testValue #Correct
eq statVar = True #Correct
```

It would seem that only statically set variables and parameters are able to be used in condition/expression due to template syntax {{  }} not being able interpret changed value at runtime. Macro syntax $(MyVar) works but can't be used in expression.
How do I get around this?

Comment: Runtime variables are not available for template expressions. Template expressions are resolved at template compile time, long before the runtime variables exist. Macro syntax is also resolved at runtime.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652609/azure-devops-yml-pipeline-if-else-condition-with-variables,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, Daniel's comment is correct.

> Template expressions are resolved at template compile time, long before the runtime variables exist.

Therefore it seems there is no easy way around this using the built in yaml funtionality provided. As link provided by Tejas's comment that emplores a hack to replace the variable value. I somehow think this will still not be able to get around the issue that template conditions are resolved at compile time.

I fear that our team is using AZ template conditions and expressions incorrectly. I will have to upskill and guide us in a beter direction.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried use template condtion?
such as

```
- pwsh: dosomething
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.myVar, true))
```

although in ms doc it says rumtime varaible cannot be used in custom condtion, but this actually works for me.

i created a test pipeline, you can try it too.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=con]True"
- pwsh: Write-Host "condtion is 1"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.con, true))
- pwsh: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=con]False"
- pwsh: Write-Host "condtion is 0"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.con, false))
```