# Azure DevOps multi-repo, multi-branch-trigger, selecting the branch to build from

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In an Azure DevOps pipeline, I had

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Web
      trigger:
        - master
    - repository: UiRepo
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Web.UI
      trigger:
        - main
[other stuff]
steps:
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: UiRepo
[other stuff]
```

This has worked fine: The pipeline ran when triggered by completion of a pull request to either the master branch of the "self" repo or the main branch of the UiRepo. The checkouts pulled from the master branch of "self" and the main branch of UiRepo.

Now I'm adding a branch called release/1.0 to each of the repos, and will introduce other release/x.x branches in the future. So now I have:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Web
      trigger:
        - master
        - release/*
    - repository: UiRepo
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Web.UI
      trigger:
        - main
        - release/*
[other stuff]
steps: # ??????
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: UiRepo
[other stuff]
```

Now the following is required:

- If the triggering branch's name ($Build.SourceBranchName) is either 'master' or 'main', check out master from "self" and main from UiRepo.
- Otherwise, check out a branch whose value is $Build.SourceBranch from both repos.

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref, I've read that I can use inline syntax in the checkout steps to include specific refs. In my case, I think this comes out as follows:

```
  - ${{ if in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName''], 'master', 'main') }}:
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.Web@refs/heads/master
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.Web.UI@refs/heads/main
  - ${{ else }}
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.Web@$(Build.SourceBranch)
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.Web.UI@$(Build.SourceBranch)

(or do I need to be using [ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] ] here instead of $(Build.SourceBranch)?)

But, by dispensing with the references in the checkout steps to "self" and UiRepo, this seems to be divorcing the connection between the checkout steps and the repos as I've already defined them. Does that matter? Is this correct anyway? If it isn't, how can I accomplish my goal?
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if/else only works with parameters, not variables. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652609/azure-devops-yml-pipeline-if-else-condition-with-variables.

Comment: @ddastrodd Ugh, so many unexpected and undocumented or poorly documented obstacles! Yet ... Bowman Zhu-MSFT, in responding, used **else** in an example and reports that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if/else you are using is named [Conditional Insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) in DevOps concept.

**Need to clarify is in this concept, it indeed can accept predefined variables， but only [which is 'Available in templates'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).**

I notice you are using `Build.Repository.SourceBranchName`, this variable not even in the list of predefined variables, let alone the concept of 'Available in templates'. **So the first part of your Conditional Insertion will not be process. Only the second part will be able to process.**

**And please do not use 'self' as the alias of the repository, this will causes ambiguity.**(Your current situation use this is no problem, this is just a suggestion.)

So basically, your pipeline definition should be like this:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    name: Repo1
    trigger:
      - master
      - release/*
  - repository: UiRepo
    type: git
    name: Repo2
    trigger:
      - main
      - release/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ if in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master', 'main') }}: #This place needs to change
    - checkout: git://BowmanCP/Repo1@refs/heads/master
    - checkout: git://BowmanCP/Repo2@refs/heads/main
- ${{ else }}:
    - checkout: git://BowmanCP/Repo1@$(Build.SourceBranch) 
    - checkout: git://BowmanCP/Repo2@$(Build.SourceBranch)
```

Works prefect on my side:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed work-through and the actual tryout! I did notice my Build.Repository.SourceBranchName was wrong, fixed it in my code and I've edited my post.

But {{else}} didn't work for me, and, in a comment above, ddastrodd advises me that it doesn't work with variables. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm First, the ${{ else }} on your side doesn't have colon. It should be ${{ else }}: . And, what the 'didn't work for me' do you mean, you mean the body of the else part will never be processed on your side? What about the if part on your side, will it be successfully to process now.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm For ddastrodd's comment, I can clearly tell you that his comment is incorrect. Yes, for common runtime variables, they really unable to be used in condition insertion. But for unusual variable like predefined variables, the situation is different. If the predefined variable is 'Available in templates', then it can be used in conditional insertion. Click the official document that I already provided in the answer, you will see that demo that the document provided also use variable.

Comment: I just checked my Git history and found I did have the colon in the actual pipeline file in the final commit before I replaced it with the not() expression. I can't explain, then, why I got an error message when the pipeline was being compiled/prepared to run. I may revert that one line to read "- ${{ else }}:" and see if it works now.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm Hi Green, any update of the issue? If this issue still exists, could you please share your newest YAML file and related issue?

Comment: With your help, I've resolved the issue. I'll provide details soon! Thanks.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm Congratulations on solving this issue! if my answer helps you solve the issue, could you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? It will helps others who meet similar issue. :)